# Switch case with while/if inside of it producing errors

Tags: c, switch-statement

I am working on a program that performs a debit transaction via pushbuttons as the keys. So far, I have been able to get the default message of "Hello" to display at the very beginning until pushbutton 1 or pushbutton 2 (PB1 and PB2) is pressed. I am having an issue with my switch statement it seems. Here's what I am trying to do: initialize with "Hello" on the screen and wait for the user to press a button. If PB1 pressed, move to case 2. Within case 2, it will display a total amount and will prompt the user to press either PB1 for ok or PB2 to cancel. If PB1 pressed, move to case 3. If PB2 pressed, return to case 1 and present the default message again until the user presses a button. Case 3 will then just determine what account they take from and move on to Case 4 to accept a pin #(I didn't include this but this is essentially the process I am trying to complete).

The push button states are as '1' while NOT pushed, and when pushed they are '0'. This is why I have tried using while (PB1 == 0), so that if PB1 is pushed, do the following. I have also tried using if (PB1 == 0) to do the same, but I seem to get stuck in a loop of just printing hello over and over again in both cases. Then, while in this loop, if I press PB1 it moves immediately to "Total is $20.75 
Press 1 for OK or 2 for CANCEL" to "Cancelled" at which point it just repeats "Cancelled" instead of going back to Case 1. "Cancelled" should only print if PB2 is pressed, which is not what I have done yet, but it still prints.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
int beginProcess = 1;


  while (1)
  {

      switch (beginProcess)
      {

          case 1:
            printf("Hello \r\n");
            PB1 = readPin1;

            while (PB1 == 0)
            {
                beginProcess = 2;
            }
            break;

          case 2:
              printf("Total is $20.75 \r\n");
              printf("Press 1 for OK or 2 for CANCEL\r\n");

              PB1 = readPin1;
              PB2 = readPin2;

              while (PB1 == 0)
              {
                  beginProcess = 3;
              }
              while (PB2 == 0)
              {
                  printf("Cancelled \r\n");
                  beginProcess = 1;
              }
             break;

          case 3:

              printf("Press 1 for chequing \r\n");
              printf("Press 2 for savings \r\n");

              PB1 = readPin1;
              PB2 = readPin2;

              while (PB1 == 0)
              {
                  beginProcess = 4;
              }

              while (PB2 == 0)
              {
                  beginProcess = 4;
              }
              break;
     }
}
```

Comment: These `while` statements look dangerous. What inside that loop would ever change things like `PB1` or `PB2`? What does `readPin1` mean? Is that a function you're not calling? Where is any user input taken?

Comment: So I wrote them like that to be a bit simpler because the program I use generates lots of code for the peripherals after being set up and it gets very messy. readPin1 is the state of push button 1.

Comment: As Tadman mentioned, those while statements are going to be a problem.  With what we can see each of those is going to block your program indefinitely. Each of those while statements needs a method of updating that allows the loop to terminate.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `while` instead of `if` for those nested blocks?

Comment: Nothing in this code makes any sense in the form it's in. No input is taken, no functions are called, loops run forever...

Comment: I just copied what I had used most recently, but I did try using 'if' and the same problem occurs.

Comment: The pin state input is initialized near the beginning of the code, and I am just calling it readPin1 for simplification. It reads the state properly as I have already checked. I know the issue with my while loops is that it runs forever, but if I put a break in it is still repeats the errors. I've even tried this with if but the problem is the same.

Comment: Does the pin state ever change throughout the program? Should it?

Comment: Yes it'll change when it's pressed so every time PB1 = readPin1 shows it is obtaining the state of the pin, and if it's pressed it will be 0.

Comment: Posted an answer that I believe will help.

Answer (score 0):

First off replace the `while` loops within the `switch` statement with `if` logic.
Second make `beginProcess` a `volatile int`

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is the type of code you are looking for.  You want your while loops to block while waiting for input.  But you need to be constantly reading both pins for input in order to change screens. This code should block in each while loop UNTIL an input is detected.  **The key is reading the pin state constantly inside the while loop!**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int readPin1(void)
{
    return 1;
}

int readPin2(void)
{
    return 0;
}

int main()
{

    int beginProcess = 1;
    int PB1 = 0;
    int PB2 = 0;

    while (1)
    {

        switch (beginProcess)
        {

            case 1:
                //printf("%i \r\n",beginProcess);
                while (PB1 == 0)
                {
                    PB1 = readPin1();
                    beginProcess = 2;
                }
            break;

            case 2:
                printf("Total is $20.75 \r\n");
                printf("Press 1 for OK or 2 for CANCEL\r\n");

                while (PB1 == 0 || PB2 == 0)
                {
                    PB1 = readPin1();
                    PB2 = readPin2();
                    if(PB1)
                    {
                        beginProcess = 3;
                    }

                    if(PB2)
                    {
                      printf("Cancelled \r\n");
                      beginProcess = 1;
                    }
                }

                break;

                case 3:
                    printf("Press 1 for chequing \r\n");
                    printf("Press 2 for savings \r\n");

                    PB1 = readPin1();
                    PB2 = readPin1();

                    while (PB1 == 0 || PB2 == 0)
                    {
                        PB1 = readPin1();
                        PB2 = readPin1();

                        if(PB1)
                        {
                             beginProcess = 4;
                        }

                        if(PB2)
                        {
                             beginProcess = 4;
                        }
                    }
              break;

              default:
              break;
          }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Below is the output when the readPin1() function always returns 1 and a default case exists.
[image: Output]

Comment: That does make sense, thanks for the reply! The issue is still present though, with the beginning "Hello" message continuing to loop infinitely even if a button is pressed. I think there's an issue with by beginProcess being 1  UNTIL a button is pushed, so it continues to execute Case 1 rather than just execute once and wait until a button is pressed. That is what I think at least.

Comment: I am seeing that behavior as well actually.  Looking at it rn.

Comment: The program is actually working, but you are getting to a state that has no case (beginProcess = 4) and the program is running the first case instead.  If you simply add a default case then it wont happen.

Comment: Where do `PB1` and `PB2` get initialized in this code?

Comment: I copied and pasted his above pseudo code.  The important aspects are the modified while loops and the default case.

Comment: Oh I do have Case 4 I just didn't include it because it's all essentially the same process (keep checking which button is pressed and do this). I do have a default case that writes "cancelling", but the repetitive looping of each case print statement is still occurring.

Comment: Ok, I updated the answer with the running code that produced that output.  As you can see I am simulating button presses.  But this doesn't got stuck spamming any cases.

Comment: Ok thank you for all of your help! I'll keep editing to see if I can fix it.